# What Mythos Type Is Mental Swiftness?

Tags: city-of-mist

If a character has a superpower of mental swiftness, does this fall under the Mobility Mythos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt, start with the archetypes on pgs. 70-73 of the Player's Guide (pgs. 104-107 in the first printing Core Book) as a quick and easy guidepost. For instance:

- "God/dess of Knowledge:" Divination (Access all knowledge) + Expression (Give or take knowledge) + Bastion (Protect knowledge)
- "Prophet or Seer:" Diviniation (Divine knowledge) + Expression (Words of truth) + Relic (Sacred item)
- "Wizard/Warlock/Witch:" Adaptation (Sorcery) + Divination (Scrying) + Subversion (Disguise)

Based on this list and the themebook descritions, I'd suggest:

- If your mental agility relates to knowledge, perception, or deduction, Divination is likely your best choice.
- If mental swiftness enables "gotcha!" reflexes and surprising creativity, Adaptation is a good fit.
- Keen defensive reactions might be best represented by Bastion or Mobility, but watch out to make sure you haven't overly narrowed your power.

In many ways, there's no one true answer here — themebooks don't have a lot of "baked in" mechanics, so the most important thing here is being able to write good (i.e. interesting, multi-faceted, and useful) power tags. **Read each relevant themebook and see if the questions it asks align well with what you think is cool and interesting about the concept**; if they don't, explore other themebooks.

Answer (score 2):

## It depends what you want that to say about your character.

You get four themebooks. They don't represent four conflicting roles that you take on each in turn - they each reflect an important part of yourself as a rift in the City of Mist. Whether or not a rift of a figure with legendary mental swiftness like, say, **Sherlock Holmes** is going to give you any Mobility-class Mythos is going to depend, at least in part, on what kind of person you were before you started rifting Sherlock Holmes. (I don't know who or what you're thinking of as a Rift. I'm thinking Sherlock Holmes, and I'm going to keep saying Sherlock Holmes.)

Mobility's essential quality, its question A, is that it grants **a useful form of movement**, as in literal actual traversal of distances, but you can wheedle that out of Sherlock easily enough as regular human movement, but with preternatural efficiency - *You Know Where To Go*. That Mobility advance that 1/session puts you in any scene you want to be is a great reveal moment for a Sherlock Holmes who watches someone running away, deduces where they're going, and heads there directly while they're trying to lose the trail.

Every Rift is capable of expressing at least three Mythos for game purposes. You can't go any higher than that, of course, but nothing says that as you drift into and out of the Rift you have to acquire the same Mythos themes each time.

But if you're building a character who's only been Touched by Sherlock Holmes, who has one Mythos and three Logos, is that one Mythos going to be Mobility? Your answer should really depend on what kind of human you are and what kind of tension you want with your Mythos.

### The Tension Between Mystery And Identity

If you only have a single Mythos themebook, you're operating basically at "human plus". Sleepers only have three Logos, so the best way of thinking of someone with one Mythos is adding something to your human identity.

A long-term part of playing City of Mist is that your Logos themes, your Identity, can Crack and be replaced by Mythos themes - or vice versa, your connection to your Mystery, your Mythos themes, can Fade and a Logos will pick up the slack. Thinking about how this might happen is generally reserved for the end of session, as you make notes on the Flipside of a theme that seems close to the edge, but the key is that it has to happen somehow. It means something for you to acquire a Mythos. It introduces a Mystery.

So, **what are you** that Sherlock Holmes reaches out to you and the first thing you get is efficient movement?

Maybe it has to do with how Mobility relates to the **capabilities** of your Logos - you're a career police detective and can deduce the heck out of things already, but this uncanny motion is both a compelling difference and makes you more capable. Or you're a resourceful street kid and you've got Training or Gear that helps you move already - the motion is how Sherlock can best relate to you, and it intensifies your focus.

Maybe it has to do with character of the Mystery inside the mythos - the thing pulling you away from your mortal life. Mobility's got some options for mysteries, too. Maybe Sherlock is the only thing helping the street kid evade some sharply more capable gangers. Maybe the detective really wants to get to that sealed case file in the deep archives, but he's got no chance of getting there... without the ability to deduce exactly where to walk so the patrols and the cameras never catch sight of him.

### You Don't Need Mobility To Move

Finally, just as a consideration, many Mythos themebooks have a decent amount of "power overlap" through their questions with letters that come after A. Divination, for example, has "what advantage does your divination give you in a fight?" and "what creative ways of using your divination have you developed?" The answers to those can easily lend themselves to being relevant when it's time to move. If you don't want to lean heavily into movement to the point of taking advances to get special tricks, you may want to look at another themebook and see if any of its questions have answers that will help you move.